# Eleventh HStack (or Other UI Component) creates compile error, "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I am creating an app with SwiftUI (Swift 5.1, XCode 11.2 (11B52), MacOS Catalina 10.15.1).
When I added components on the view, at some point I got an error.
To identify the cause, I simplified code like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Then, I got an error at the first HStack, which says "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments."

If I comment out one of the eleven "HStack"s, the error is gone.

I would like to know what is happening.
Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Group { ... }`.

SwiftUI has a limit of ten items per view. You can get around this by using `Group`  So if you need more items. You group them together. You can only have 10 Groups per view, due to the 10 item limit, but you can just contain them inside a `Group` too. Though if you are getting to nested groups, it maybe better to refactor your code and write it in a different way, either using a `ForEach` or making you code more componentised.

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Okay")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HackingwithSwift has a fantastic article explaining why. You can see it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-group-views-together)

> This is because SwiftUI’s view building system has various code designed to let us add 1 view, 2 views, 3 views, or 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 views, but not for 11 and beyond – that doesn’t work.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Adding "Group{}" worked! It is really tricky...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem with `VStack(spacing: pad)`. This replaced all my `Spacer()` entries, which were using up half of the 10 views limit.

That will not fix the example code the way `Group{}` does. But it may be enough to get you out of a hole.